# GUI, BoxLayout adding a panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

Studying BoxLayout and GUI in general. I want to place a panel on a frame. Later I'll add an identical panel and will test BoxLaoyout. But I can't understand why this code produces not a panel sized 200x400 but just a red point in the middle of the left side of the frame (with coordinates about (300,0)).

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    public View(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        Border border = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.RED, Color.BLACK);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setSize(200, 400);
        p1.setBorder(border);
        p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        panel.add(p1);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout manager (`BoxLayout`) is using the preferred size of the components of the container it is managing. By default, the preferred size of a empty `JPanel` is 0x0, adding in the border has produced a preferred size closer to 2x2

When using layout managers, calling `setSize` is meaningless, as the layout manager will override anything you specify when the container is revalidate

**Updated**

It would appear that the combination of both `BoxLayout`s seems to be playing against you.  If I remove the second `BoxLayout` from `p1`, it seems to work okay.

Also, `BoxLayout` seems to want to work with the maximum size of the component...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class View extends JFrame {

    public View() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        Border border = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.RED, Color.BLACK);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel() {
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 400);
            }
        };
        p1.setBorder(border);
        p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(p1);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new View();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already experimented with the preferred size.      Instead of setSize I used this line of code: p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400)); But the result was the same.